# How to have one Javascript in the MasterPage handling all ASP.NET TextBox Controls?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am a new ASP.NET Webforms developer and I am trying to develop a simple web-based application using ASP.NET with C# and Twitter Bootstrap v2. I am struggling right now with the [JQuery DateTime Picker](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) that is an additional plug-in to Twitter Bootstrap. The problem is I have three forms in three different pages. Each form has two TextBoxes controls for inserting the datetime using this plugin. To use this plugin, I have to add the following script to the Head of the page as many as I have TextBoxes. It means if I have two TextBoxes, then I have to add it twice.

***Javascript Code:***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                language: 'en',
                pick12HourFormat: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

***ASP.NET Code:***

```
<div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date">
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDateNew" runat="server">
                                    </asp:TextBox>
                                    <span class="add-on"><i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
```

What I want is just adding it once in the MasterPage and it will handle any number of textboxes. **Could you please tell me how to do that (if possible)?**

Comment: Use class instead of id

Answer (score 0):

You can select by class instead of selecting with id. You can apply same class to multiple and this makes your solution. Like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.picker').datetimepicker({
                language: 'en',
                pick12HourFormat: true
            });
        });
    </script>

 <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDateNew" runat="server" CssClass="picker">
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to select your datepicker textboxes by class and not by id. If you do this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.mydatepicker').datetimepicker({
            language: 'en',
            pick12HourFormat: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

then you can do this :

```
<div id="datetimepicker1" class="input-append date mydatepicker">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDateNew" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <span class="add-on"><i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

Please note I did put the class on your `div`, not on the `TextBox` self, cause in your example the element that was selected by the jquery selector was the `div` , not the `textBox`